# Render Cards dynamically via XML view

Tags: sapui5

Is there a way to render the `sap.f.Card` control dynamically with an XML view? With aggregation binding maybe? I only used aggregation binding with lists and tables so far...

I need to render some cards dynamically on a main view but I want to stay with the MVC concept. That's why I don't prefer to render the cards in the controller. My Card is also very complex and has multiple controls in it. (Text, Status Indicator, Progress Indicator, etc.)

Is there a way of implementing that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- In Fiori, Cards are usually rendered within [`sap.f.GridContainer`](https://ui5.sap.com/#/topic/cca5ee5d63ca44c89318f8496a58f9f2) (In fact, it was initially called [`sap.f.CardContainer`](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/commit/5d5feba426cc662849fb91ce0e027e6cc7332dd7)).
- Just like with Tables and Lists, you can bind `<items>` to the `GridContainer` too with the Card as a template control:

  > ```xml
  > <f:GridContainer xmlns:f="sap.f"
  >   width="100%"
  >   snapToRow="true"
  >   items="{
  >     path: '/myCardItems',
  >     templateShareable: false
  >   }">
  >   <f:layout>
  >     <f:GridContainerSettings rowSize="84px" columnSize="84px" gap="8px" />
  >   </f:layout>
  >   <f:layoutXS>
  >     <f:GridContainerSettings rowSize="70px" columnSize="70px" gap="8px" />
  >   </f:layoutXS>
  >   <f:items>
  >     <f:Card> <!-- template -->
  >       <f:header>
  >         <card:Header xmlns:card="sap.f.cards" title="{title}" />
  >       </f:header>
  >       <f:layoutData>
  >         <f:GridContainerItemLayoutData minRows="..." columns="..." />
  >       </f:layoutData>
  >     </f:Card>
  >   </f:items>
  > </f:GridContainer>
  > ```

  The above snippet is from the [Demo Kit sample](https://ui5.sap.com/#/entity/sap.f.GridContainer/sample/sap.f.sample.GridContainerDragAndDropFromList) that has an aggregation binding.

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. Thanks! Should have read the documentation more carefully I guess....

Comment: @Ardit Probably that sample didn't exist yet when you were asking the question ;) It's fairly new.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it using the [Grid layout](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.ui.layout.Grid) with`content` aggregation

**view.xml**

```
<core:View
    xmlns:core="sap.ui.core"
    xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc"
    xmlns="sap.m"
    xmlns:l="sap.ui.layout"
    xmlns:fc="sap.f"
    xmlns:card="sap.f.cards"
        controllerName="path.Main"
    xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <Page title="Main" class="sapUiContentPadding">
        <content>
            <!-- Cards data binding -->
            <l:Grid containerQuery="true" id="cardsGrid" defaultSpan="XL2 L4" class="gridProgressIndicator" hSpacing="0" content="{/cards}">
                <fc:Card class="sapUiMediumMargin" width="300px">
                    <fc:header>
                        <card:Header
                        title="{title}"
                        subtitle="{subTitle}"
                        iconSrc="{icon}"/>
                    </fc:header>
                    <fc:content>
                        <VBox
                        height="115px"
                        class="sapUiSmallMargin"
                        justifyContent="SpaceBetween">
                            <HBox justifyContent="SpaceBetween">
                                <ComboBox
                                width="120px"
                                placeholder="To City"
                                items="{items}">
                                    <core:Item key="{key}" text="{text}" />
                                </ComboBox>
                                <ComboBox
                                width="120px"
                                placeholder="To City"
                                items="{items}">
                                    <core:Item key="{key}" text="{text}" />
                                </ComboBox>
                            </HBox>
                            <HBox justifyContent="SpaceBetween">
                                <DatePicker width="186px" placeholder="Choose Date ..."/>
                                <Button text="Book" press="onBookPress" type="Emphasized" />
                            </HBox>
                        </VBox>
                    </fc:content>
                </fc:Card>
            </l:Grid>
        </content>
    </Page>
</core:View>
```

**controller.js**

```
bindCardsGrid: function() {         
  var rowData = [
      { "title": "Title 1", "subTitle": "SubTitle 1", "icon": "sap-icon://menu2", "items": [{ "key": "CV1", "text": "CV1"}, { "key": "CV2", "text": "CV2"}, { "key": "CV3", "text": "CV3"},{ "key": "CV4", "text": "CV4"}]},
      { "title": "Title 2", "subTitle": "SubTitle 2", "icon": "sap-icon://add-contact", "items": [{ "key": "CV1", "text": "CV1"}, { "key": "CV2", "text": "CV2"}, { "key": "CV3", "text": "CV3"},{ "key": "CV4", "text": "CV4"}]},
      { "title": "Title 3", "subTitle": "SubTitle 3", "icon": "sap-icon://business-objects-experience", "items": [{ "key": "CV1", "text": "CV1"}, { "key": "CV2", "text": "CV2"}, { "key": "CV3", "text": "CV3"},{ "key": "CV4", "text": "CV4"}]},
      { "title": "Title 4", "subTitle": "SubTitle 4", "icon": "sap-icon://process", "items": [{ "key": "CV1", "text": "CV1"}, { "key": "CV2", "text": "CV2"}, { "key": "CV3", "text": "CV3"},{ "key": "CV4", "text": "CV4"}]}
  ];       
  var oModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel();
  oModel.setData({ "cards": rowData });
  this.getView().setModel(oModel);
},
```

**output**

[image]

Comment: Thank you! That already helped me. I am using a GridContaier for rendering, (from the sap.f. library) Does the aggregation binding there also work? There it  says "encountered unknown setting 'content' for class sap.f.GridContainer"...

Comment: I am using `sap.ui.layout.Grid` layout control. Updated my complete view

Comment: I tried that out, thank you. The problem I have with the `sap.ui.layout.Grid` is that the content always resizes. Or if I change the content to fix width and height, they always overlap when resizing... I want the content to be fixed in height and width and it should render underneath if the screen size changes. I didn't find any option for the `sap.ui.layout.Grid` doing so yet. With the `sap.f.GridContaier` it works fine but there the aggregation binding does not work, or I didn't find a way to do so yet...Any idea maybe? Thanks again